# Grails 3.2.3 is incompatible with JDK 9

Tags: java, grails

My Configuration is

```
Grails Version: 3.3.2 
Groovy Version: 2.4.13 
JVM Version: 9.0.4
```

I have got below error. Need solution of this

> Error initializing classpath: Could not determine java version
>   from '9.0.4'. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Answer (score 3):

> Need solution of this

There isn't one.  Grails 3.3.2 does not support Java 9.

Comment: Are you sure about that 'Grails 3.3.2 does not support Java 9' ??

Comment: Jeff is Grails co founder. He knows.

Comment: "Are you sure..." - Yes.  One issue is that several of our core dependencies don't support Java 9.  For example, Grails 3 is built on Spring Boot and Spring Boot won't support Java 9 until Spring Boot 2.  Grails 3.3.2 uses Boot 1.5.8.

Comment: Note that while you can not build Grails 3.x/Spring-boot 1.x with Java 9 (which is now End of Life) - you can compile with jdk8 and run in jdk9/10.